# Replace parameter with estimate for confidence interval. Case Beta distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, estimators, beta-distribution

I'm trying to get a confidence interval for the mean of a beta distribution $B(\theta,1)$, using $[\hat\theta - z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta};\hat\theta + z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta}]$ as interval.

My pdf is $f_X = \theta x^{\theta-1}$; $0\leq x \leq 1$; $\theta > 0$.

And the mean is $\mu_x = \frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$. Then what I need to do is to make that expression appear in the interval. Therefore I get:

$$\frac{1}{\hat\theta + z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta}} \leq \frac{1}{\theta+1} \leq \frac{1}{\hat\theta - z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta}}$$

Now multiplying by $\theta$

$$\frac{\theta}{\hat\theta + z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta}} \leq \frac{\theta}{\theta+1} \leq \frac{\theta}{\hat\theta - z_{1-\alpha/2}\hat\sigma_{\hat\theta}}$$

The problem is I get $\theta$ in the lower and upper bound. In this case is ok to replace $\theta$ with $\hat\theta$? I think since we don't know $\theta$ we can replace it with something we know i.e it's estimate. Is my reasoning correct? Is that simple? or I'm missing something?

Comment: What $\hat\theta$ are you using? MLE? For a large sample CI, you can find the limiting distribution of $\hat\theta/(1+\hat\theta)$ from that of $\hat\theta$.

Comment: Or perhaps rewrite as $\theta/(1+\theta)=1/(1+1/\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom, rewriting like that solves the problem.

Comment: You can post an answer then.